# Insert into PDO with IF clause

Tags: php, pdo

I need some help with inserting some data into a sql server table using the IF clause.
I have the return of an API that I insert in the table of the sql server.
However, as I will schedule my code every day to get the update from the API to see if there is anything new, but every time it executes the code it inserts the same information into the table.

The most logical thing I thought was to make a select in the table where I will insert the data and create an IF, where it compares what is in the table and my return from the array. If it’s the same, it doesn’t do anything, if it’s different, insert it. However, the else is not being validated, even if the return of the IF is false.

I've tryed If, ifelse, If(): else: endif; but i couldnt.

Can someone help me please?

```
   $resultado = json_decode(curl_exec($curl),true);
    curl_close($curl);



//! Teste SELECT:

$qyS = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare("SELECT idSkill FROM LIVEPERSON_SKILLS");
$qyS->execute();
$selectResult = $qyS->fetchAll();

foreach ($selectResult as $indSelect => $retSelect){
    $idSkillComp = $retSelect['idSkill'];


//* 6 | Abertura do laço ['skills']
    foreach ($resultado as $indice => $infoSkills){
        $idSkill = $infoSkills['id'];
        $name = $infoSkills['name'];
        $deleted = $infoSkills['deleted'];
        $dh_insert = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

//* 7 | Inserção dados no banco:

    if($idSkill == $idSkillComp){
        echo "error";
    }else{
    $qyI = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare("INSERT INTO LIVEPERSON_SKILLS 
        (DH_INSERT,idSkill,name,deleted) 
        VALUES (:d, :i, :n, :x)");

    $qyI->bindValue(":d",$dh_insert);
    $qyI->bindValue(":i",$idSkill);
    $qyI->bindValue(":n",$name);
    $qyI->bindValue(":x",$deleted);
    $qyI->execute();
        }


    }
  }
```

Comment: If you're not doing a SELECT, you should use `$query->exec` instead of `$query->fetchAll`.

Comment: And if it doesn't do the INSERT, then it has to do the else clause.  That's just the way it works.  Have you printed `$idSkill` and `$idSkillComp` to make sure they're exactly what you expect?

Comment: @TimRoberts I did the select on top, because I had to open it with foreach. The result of the query inside the foreach is $ idSkillComp

Comment: @ADyson sorry, i will try to explain it better. I replaced the fetchall with the execute and inserted it too. But it is still in a loop, does the if and then the ifelse, but keeps inserting. I typed $ idSkill and $ idSkillComp and both return what I want to insert. I print $idSkill and $idSkillComp and both return what I want to insert. The variables $idSkill and $idSkillComp come from within a foreach that I had to open to get to them, as they are arrays ($idSkill API, $idSkillComp Select query)

Comment: Please confirm this understanding of your question: This code, in the case where **$idSkill** and **$idSkillComp** are equal, executes the INSERT?

Comment: @DonR, No. If they are the same, don't do it, if they are different, do it. That's how it was supposed to be, but it's not working

Comment: So yes, that is your question :) Are you *certain* that the INSERT is being run when the values are the same? Are you *certain* that there is nowhere else an INSERT might be happening? Could we see more of the actual code?

Comment: @DonR I'm sure yes, I spent the whole afternoon watching and reviewing this here to try to fix it myself. I'm new with development hahaha. There is no other place that may be being inserted, just this execute that I call for insert, the other is for select only. Yes, I will update the post with more information about the code.

Comment: @Phil a little lack of attention haha i will correct. Could this be impacting the if?

Comment: You don't need to call `$query->execute()` since `$Conexao->query()` also executes the statement. The call to `execute()` might insert duplicate data. What you should do is use `$Conexao->prepare()` with parameter placeholders, then `execute()`, passing in an array of values

Comment: As for your comparison issue, do some simple debugging. Ideally, step through your code with a debugger but at a minimum, start putting in some `echo` statements, eg in your various loops... `echo "Query iteration $RetQyindSkill, idSkill: $idSkillComp";`, `echo "API result iteration $indice, idSkill: $idSkill";`, etc

Comment: @Phil I removed the line $doQuery = $query-> execute () and made the insert, thanks for the tip. Regarding the echo of values, I already did it in all the parameters of the foreach, and everyone is returning what I really want to insert. I even did the vardump and realized that the value returned from the API is integer and that of the query is string, I did the conversion of the string to integer with intval () but without success too. Idk what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good afternoon. I identified what was going on in that case. In the second foreach I asked for the opening from each row found in the query (I believe it is the normal behavior of the foreach). Therefore, when inserting the data, I ended up inserting a duplicate, as it was 36 skillIds for each line found in the select.

I solved this issue leaving the rule inside the insert, changing it to insert select instead of making the select and then compare with what would be inserted.

Here's how it went:

```
   $resultado = json_decode(curl_exec($curl),true);
    curl_close($curl);

    foreach ($resultado as $indInfoSkills => $infoSkills){
        $idSkillPrepare = array($infoSkills['id']);
        $idSkill =  implode(",",$idSkillPrepare);
        $name = $infoSkills['name'];
        $deleted = $infoSkills['deleted'];
        $dh_insert = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $qyI = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO LIVEPERSON_SKILLS (DH_INSERT,idSkill,name,deleted) 
            SELECT :dhInsert, 
                   :idSkill, 
                   :name, 
                   :deleted 
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT idSkill 
                              FROM LIVEPERSON_SKILLS 
                              WHERE idSkill = '$idSkill')");
        
    $qyI->bindValue(":dhInsert",$dh_insert);
    $qyI->bindValue(":idSkill",$idSkill);
    $qyI->bindValue(":name",$name);
    $qyI->bindValue(":deleted",$deleted);
    $qyI->execute();

    }
```

Thanks so much for everyone who tried to help me.